# Suggested modification to Help Center "How Do I Search" text

Tags: feature-request, help-center-proposed

The "How Do I Search" text in the Help Center describes searching for tags by enclosing them in brackets.  It also describes using a wildcard in word search terms.  But it doesn't mention that wildcards can be used inside tag brackets.

I assume a similar situation with multi-word tags applies in other sites, but Super User has a lot of "families of tags".  A common usage of these on Super User is manufacturers and software publishers; collections of tags that start with a manufacturer/publisher name, to which is appended a product or clarifying term as a multi-word tag.

Searching on the manufacturer/publisher name in brackets returns nothing because manufacturer name tags have been deprecated as meta terms; search terms are exact matches.  If you want to see all related tags, you can include a wildcard within the brackets.

The ability to do that isn't obvious from the Help Center text.  My suggestion is to expand the guidance in the basic tips section to make this explicit, along these lines:

> Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (`*`) anywhere in the word, like `encour*` or `Ex*nge`.  **The wildcard can also be used within tag brackets to include all tags containing the sample text.**

(Bold used to highlight added wording.)